# Product ID for uber connect in nairobi

Tags: uber-api

I'm only actually trying to use deeplinks, not even the api, but I can't find any way to get the product ID (uber connect) that I need without it, so I am attempting to get products.

`https://sandbox-api.uber.com/v1.2/products`

I am getting an the error `"This endpoint requires at least one of the following scopes: ride_request.estimate"` which I understand is because I have not gained scope access from uber.

(I did include that scope in the 0Auth request.)

It has been absolutely impossible to reach them. I filled out a form and it said they'd get back to me sometime but they are very busy.

An entire project is held up for hours over this detail and I'm really struggling for how to solve this. Is there a way to gain access or even make a sandbox request without that scope?

Or would someone be kind enough enough to run the call and let me know the response for `[latitude]=-1.2741798[longitude]=36.791785`

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm following up here that uber now has a deep link generator that makes the above process unnecessary. Which is good because reaching them or getting support is next to impossible.